# Convert map into desired map

Tags: arraylist, groovy, hashmap, flatten

I have a `map` with structure as below :-

```
def map = [107:[[107, "Module 01", 1], [107, "Module New", 6]], 109:[[109, "Module 04", 1]]]
```

We have a task to represent this `map` as below structure :-

```
Application | Module 01 | Module New | Module 04
107         |    1      |     6      |   0
109         |    0      |     0      |   1
```

So for this representation, I want to filter `map` as below :-

```
def outputMap = [moduleList:["Module 01", "Module New", "Module 04"], dataList:[[107:[1, 6, 0]], [109:[0, 0, 1]]]]
```

So for achieving this, I have done as below :-

```
def getFilteredMap(Map map) {
        def moduleList = map.findResults {
            it.value.findResults { it[1] }
        }.flatten()

        def dataList = []

        map*.key.each { app ->
            def tempMap = [:]
            tempMap[app] = map.findResults {
                it.value.findResults {
                    (it[0] == app) ? it[2] : 0
                }
            }.flatten()
            dataList << tempMap
        }

    return ["moduleList" : moduleList, "dataList" : dataList]
}

def map = [107:[[107, "Module 01", 1], [107, "Module New", 6]], 109:[[109, "Module 04", 1]]]
def outputMap = [moduleList:["Module 01", "Module New", "Module 04"], dataList:[[107:[1, 6, 0]], [109:[0, 0, 1]]]]
assert outputMap == getFilteredMap(map)
```

But as you can see `getFilteredMap()` method to filter map as desire output is not very good.

**Note** :- Module name may be repeated here, but I want only unique module Names list means as `Set`.

Can anyone suggest better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider extracting the common code into a new method.

(Edit: I have also used `collect` and `collectEntries` to clean up the `dataList` section, as suggested by [RudolphEst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2111876/rudolphest))

```
def findAsFlat(map, f) {
    map.findResults { it.value.findResults(f) }.flatten()
}

def getFilteredMap(Map map) {
    def moduleList = findAsFlat(map, { it[1] })

    def dataList = map*.key.collect { app ->
        map.collectEntries ([:]) { 
            [app, findAsFlat(map, {(it[0] == app) ? it[2] : 0})]
        }
    }

    return ["moduleList" : moduleList, "dataList" : dataList]
}

def map = [107:[[107, "Module 01", 1], [107, "Module New", 6]], 109:[[109, "Module 04", 1]]]
def outputMap = [moduleList:["Module 01", "Module New", "Module 04"], dataList:[[107:[1, 6, 0]], [109:[0, 0, 1]]]]
assert outputMap == getFilteredMap(map)
```

This is clearer than the original and would facilitate unit tests.

Comment: `collect` can still be used here to remove the creation of and appending  to `tempMap`

Comment: Yes your solution looks much cleaner...:)

Comment: I've cleaned up the `dataList` section, per suggestion... It took me awhile to see the double iteration (i.e. a list of maps).

Comment: @RudolphEst appreciate your suggestion...:)

Answer (score 1):

Because your input is in a map instead of a nice flat list, the best plan up I can recommend is to create the `dataList` as follows (`collect` into it instead of appending [`<<`] into it)

```
   def dataList =  map*.key.collect { app ->
        [(app) : map.findResults {
            it.value.findResults {
                (it[0] == app) ? it[2] : 0
            }
        }.flatten()]
    }
```

I would probably also recommend using `collectEntries` and make `dataList` a map instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions...:)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got:

```
def transformMap( map ) {
  // 1st collect all names to be used as 0-filled "grid-pattern"
  def moduleList = map.values().inject( [] ){ res, curr ->
    for( v in curr ) res << v[ 1 ]
    res
  }.unique()

// now fill the dataList, positioning the values according to the grid
  def dataList = map.inject( [:].withDefault{ [0] * moduleList.size() } ){ res, curr ->
    for( v in curr.value ) res[ curr.key ][ moduleList.indexOf( v[ 1 ] ) ] = v[ 2 ]
    res
  }.inject( [] ){ res, curr ->
    res << [( curr.key ): curr.value]
    res
  }

  [moduleList: moduleList, dataList: dataList]
}


def m = [107: [[107, "Module 01", 1], [107, "Module New", 6]], 109: [[109, "Module 04", 1]]]
def expected = [moduleList:["Module 01", "Module New", "Module 04"], dataList:[[107:[1, 6, 0]], [109:[0, 0, 1]]]]

assert expected == transformMap( m )
```

Comment: This is an impressive solution, but is it not a little over complicated? What was wrong with the way the `moduleList` was created initially? Kudo's on the `unique` though, I did not think of repeated module names.

Comment: it is as complicated as the business logic requires it to be.

Comment: I politely disagree, the business logic has very little to do with the choice of using functions provided by the API (such as `addAll` and `collect`, `findResults`), instead of creating the program by only using the `inject` reduction. I think the OP's original solution was simpler, more readable and more maintainable.

Comment: @RudolphEst I'm sorry, I didn't mention here but module Names is not unique here...it may be repeated..but I want it's as `Set`